# Is there a nifty way to Convert an array of list/hash's to a useable string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have the following array of hashes/lists.

```
var someArray = [
   { htmlElem : "<div>", txt: "something In Div" },
   { htmlElem : "</div>", txt: "baddabing!" }
]
```

of course, I know I can just $.each() it and concatenate the values etc..  but i am looking for something a bit more nifty/robust as I have a feeling there is some jQuery ninja way that can cut to the chase here.

This is what i want to end up with. A string

```
<div>something In Div</div>baddabing!
```

Is there something a bit more prolific than just each'ing thru it and .join()'ing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to automatically concatenate the values in the object, as the properties in an object doesn't have a fixed order. You need to specify which order to concatenate them.

You can use the `$.map` method to process the items in the array, then join them:

```
var s = $.map(someArray, function(e){
  return e.htmlElem + e.txt;
}).join('');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Aya4F/

Comment: thanks, yeah - I have something like this - I was hoping there was some sort of "flatten" or "serialize" kinda thing that would do the trick, but i appreciate your reply. I'll just go with this.! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Array.prototype.reduce`

---

```
var someArray = [
   { htmlElem : "<div>", txt: "something In Div" },
   { htmlElem : "</div>", txt: "baddabing!" }
];

var str = someArray.reduce(function (prev, curr) {
    return prev + curr.htmlElem + curr.txt;
}, '');
```

---

I'm sure you could also make a generic way so that the names of the keys don't matter, but that's the general idea.

Comment: +1, but I think you just mean `prev + curr.htmlElem + curr.txt;` – the `prev` should already be a string. (And you need an initializer – the empty string should do nicely.)

Comment: You're right. What you suggested would make it return `[object Object]</div>baddabing!` though. But I can just pass an empty string as a starting value, and it's fixed.

Comment: yeah, that is a good suggestion - problem is - we are supporting IE8 and I don't want to create a polyfill for this. Otherwise this would be a nice solution.

Comment: The poly would be small, though. I think it's better to use them and go for readability.